# Craft 3 - How do you programatically update a field type that is a Category?

Tags: plugin-development, categories, craft3

I have a Category element, `locations`, which I am trying to update programatically through a Craft 3 plugin that reads data from a CSV.

The `locations` category has a Field Layout: `latitude` (Number), `longitude` (Number), `nearbyLocations` (Categories).

**I am having trouble updating a locations' `nearbyLocations` field**. *I am inserting an array of Categories* into the `nearbyLocations` field on the `setFieldValues()` call.

A TypeError gets thrown deep in the bowels of Craft:

> craft\helpers\StringHelper::toLowerCase() must be of the type string, 
>   array given, called in 
>   /home/vagrant/code/vendor/craftcms/cms/src/helpers/Db.php on line 448

Below is my code:

**$new_nearby_locations is an array of Category elements.**

```php
$new_nearby_locations = [];
foreach ($nearby_locations_slugs_from_csv as $nearby_location_slug) {
  $nearby_location = Category::find()
                    ->slug($nearby_location_slug)
                    ->one();

  if (!is_null($nearby_location)) {
      array_push($new_$nearby_locations, $nearby_location);
  }
}
```

**Update $category's field values.**

```php
$category = Category::find()->slug($slug)->one();
$category->setFieldValues([
    'latitude' => $new_latitude, // previously defined
    'longitude' => $new_longitude, // previously defined        
    'nearbyLocations' => $new_nearby_locations
]);
```

**Save the changes**

```php
 Craft::$app->elements->saveElement($category);
```

I am suspicious that updating `nearbyLocations` by inserting an array of Category elements is wrong. If so, what is the right format?

Or am I doing something else wrong.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should insert an array of ids - not an array of elements - in order to make it work. That's basically it

```
$new_$nearby_locations[] = $nearby_location->id;
```

(that's usually better than array push too)

Edit

But your error message sounds more like your slug is an Array or something like this. Do you change any other fields somewhere?